# Adding OData Connected Service to the project failed: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path1

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, odata

I am using ASP API 2 with OData v3 and Visual Studio 2017 Community  .. I am trying to consume this API by [OData Connected Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=laylaliu.ODataConnectedService), and I followed this [instructions](http://odata.github.io/odata.net/OData-Client-Code-Generation-Tool/) then it throws error:

**Adding OData Connected Service to the project failed: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1**
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8FLv.png)

so how to handle that issue ?

Answer (score 7):

To clarify CRice's response:

Install the WCF Data Services 5.0 for OData V3
 [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=WCF+Data+Services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=WCF%20Data%20Services)

1-Add the **Odata Connected Service** extension

2-Verify registry contents:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.0]
"Version"="5.0.51212.0"
"InstallLocation"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft WCF Data Services\\5.0\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services\VS 2014 Tooling]
"Version"="5.0.51212.0"
"InstallLocation"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft WCF Data Services\\5.0\\"
```

3-Use the **Add Connected Service Reference** context menu from VS 2017

Comment: I was able to use this to connect to an odata service

Comment: Crazy why the reg has to be hacked and the OData Service install doesn't do it... /grr, btw this helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I had another error

> Adding OData Connected Service to the project failed: Cannot write to
> a closed TextWriter.

But when I search for it I land here, that's why I want to leave an answer for that problem.

In my case metadata xml file with edmx contained the following line

```
<Annotation Term="Core.SchemaVersion" String="1.0.0" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm"/>
```

The problem was solved by removing this line.

Answer (score 0):

There has been success for some people with adding registry keys that tell the connected service plugin where the WCF Data Services files are installed.

See https://github.com/OData/lab/issues/64

You can try make a .reg file with the following after you check the paths and run it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services\VS 2014 Tooling]
"Version"="5.6.61587.0"
"InstallLocation"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.6\"
```

I think if this will work may depend on what version of visual studio you are running, it has not fixed the issue for me yet.  I will update this answer when I find out how to get it going in VS2017.

Comment: Finally some one responded :) , I think this solution is for WCF .. but I want to use OData with API .. by the way, I've tried it with vs 2013 and it worked so perfect

Comment: @AmirImam Yes it seems like all the tooling is really old and there is no new support for VS2017.